# javax.swing.event.EventListenerList in non-GUI applications

Tags: java, events, listener

Is it a good idea to use `javax.swing.event.EventListenerList` in `non-GUI applications`?  I'd like to use it but it is a part of `Swing` and my application has no GUI elements.  So, I don't want to use `classes` from `javax.swing` (just on principle).  Should I use `EventListenerList` in spite of this or I should just copy / write my own realization of `EventListenerList`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see any reason why not to use **[EventListenerList](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/event/EventListenerList.html)**.

### Keypoints:

1. It is designed to do what you want, so there is no need to re-invent the wheel.
2. It has no dependency what-so-ever of any Swing related stuff (besides being in package "javax.swing"). It doesn't import/need/use any component or Class in the Swing package, so no overhead for your non-GUI application.
3. It is targeted to **[`EventListeners`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/EventListener.html)** (which are not at all Swing-specific) and it is "lightweight".
   Quoting the **[Java docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/event/EventListenerList.html)**:
   "...A class that holds a list of EventListeners..."
   "...The main benefits that this class provides are that it is relatively cheap in the case of no listeners, and it provides serialization for event-listener lists in a single place, as well as a degree of MT safety (when used correctly)..."

### Conclusion:

There seems to be no reason for a non-GUI app to refrain from using this Class. :)

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  I know all of the keypoints You placed above.  The question is more philosophical then practical.  That is my opinion.  So, I'll use the 'EventListenerList' unless I come up with another alternative.  (I've already developed _my own_ realization of 'EventListenerList' which is to be tested and compared with 'javax.swing' variant).

Comment: EventListenerList is a rather small Class anyway (if you look at the source-code). You can just copy-paste the parts you need, but being such a compact implementation, I don't really see the reason.

Comment: I've wrote my realization which is much faster than the original with **big** number of listeners. But with _small_ number it works slower about in 2-3 times... So, I'll use the `EventListenerList`...

Comment: Since Java 9, there is a reason to not use EventListenerList: if you have a modular project, you need to add a dependency to java.desktop to use the EventListenerList. Since I do nothing about desktop, and want to keep dependencies as low as possible, I simply don't use EventListenerList.

Answer (score 0):

Java has several EventListener. Which one should be used depends on the thrown events. If you don't have a GUI, listeners from `javax.swing` don't seem to be the right ones. Please take a look at [Oracles Writing Event Listeners Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/).

Comment: That's a _swing_ tutorial.  It's the exact opposite of this question.

Comment: I don't use listeners from `javax.swing`. I've defined my own listeners (which implement `java.util.EventListener`) with which I want to use the `javax.swing.event.EventListenerList`.